# Using ScrollView in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have one ListView and two ImageButtons in my Nav Drawer. My problem is, if my Listview expands beyond screen, it scrolls to show all the listview items only, not the two imagebuttons below.

To solve this, I tried adding ScrollView to wrap the LinearLayout (@+id/drawer), but it gives me below error.

Is it possible to have a NavDrawer with extra items (other than listview) and have an overall scroller?

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/texturebg2"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/texturebg2"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/col3"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/menu_selector" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/extrabuttons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" >
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/credit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription = "@string/credit"
                android:onClick="openCredit"
                android:src="@drawable/information"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton2"
                android:padding="8dip"
                android:text="@string/credit" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/exit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription = "@string/exit"
                android:onClick="closeApp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_exit"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton2"
                android:padding="8dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/exit" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

**LogCat**

```
01-09 14:04:02.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-09 14:04:02.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): Process: com.migrationdesk.mylibman, PID: 1072
01-09 14:04:02.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.migrationdesk.mylibman/com.migrationdesk.mylibman.NavContainer}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams
01-09 14:04:02.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
01-09 14:04:02.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
01-09 14:04:02.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-09 14:04:02.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
01-09 14:04:02.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-09 14:04:02.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-09 14:04:02.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
01-09 14:04:02.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 14:04:02.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-09 14:04:02.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
01-09 14:04:02.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
01-09 14:04:02.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-09 14:04:02.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams
01-09 14:04:02.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isDrawerView(DrawerLayout.java:857)
01-09 14:04:02.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.closeDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1058)
01-09 14:04:02.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at com.migrationdesk.mylibman.NavContainer.displayView(NavContainer.java:202)
01-09 14:04:02.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at com.migrationdesk.mylibman.NavContainer.onCreate(NavContainer.java:116)
01-09 14:04:02.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
01-09 14:04:02.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-09 14:04:02.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
01-09 14:04:02.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace? And why you want to use framelayout in this ?

Comment: updated ... framelayout is the container of my fragments ... this is how I found all tutorials abour NavDrawer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/extrabuttons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" >
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/credit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription = "@string/credit"
                android:onClick="openCredit"
                android:src="@drawable/information"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton2"
                android:padding="8dip"
                android:text="@string/credit" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/exit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription = "@string/exit"
                android:onClick="closeApp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_exit"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton2"
                android:padding="8dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/exit" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Put above layout inside different xml file and call it footer.xml

now in java code where you set the adapter:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer, null, true);

listView.addFooterView(View);
```

And just keep ListView in drawer like:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/col3"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/menu_selector" />
```

And now your list view will scroll to this view.

Answer (score 0):

This seems pretty familiar to me as I faced the same problem a short time ago. Firstly, wrapping a `ListView` into a `ScrollView` is generally not a good idea (and probably, if you use the Android SDK integrated version of Eclipse, you received a warning), because `ListView` has an scroller itself.

Secondly, the problem is that due to your layout definition, the `ListView` is expanding to the bottom of your screen, which makes your two images unreachable.

I solved this issue wrapping the content I wanted to show within a `LinearLayout` with `vertical` orientation, something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/chanlist_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >
  </ListView>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_chanlist_close"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:onClick="btn_close"
    android:background="@drawable/botones"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="@string/btn_close" />          
</LinearLayout>
```

The "problem" is that the layout will try to fit the screen to the whole layout definition, i.e. if you have too much elements in your layout, your `ListView` will be compressed in a short amount of space and it will make it hard to scroll. Try to simplify your layout as much as you can.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `background` image as it will extend the `wrap_content` or you can use empty image and extend it's size in code using `ImageView.getLayoutParams().width = width;` or `ImageView.getLayoutParams().height = height;`